# How to get PulseAudio's source priority via DBus

Tags: linux, dbus, pulseaudio

I am working on a `golang` software that aims at dealing (muting and unmuting) with the currently enabled microphone in a Linux system using pulseaudio.

My software is trying to use the `DBUs` interface to interact with pulseaudio.

If the computer has more than one microphone connected to it, I need to find the enabled one by looking at the `priority` property of my sources.

For example this is a trimmed output from the `pacmd list-sources` command:

```
4 source(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor>
...        
        priority: 1030
...
    index: 1
        name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
...
        priority: 9039
...
    index: 2
        name: <combined.monitor>
...
        priority: 1000
...
  * index: 4
        name: <alsa_input.usb-046d_0825_6C7C2E60-02.mono-fallback>
...
        priority: 9040
...
```

In fact, in my system, the source with index 4 is the active one.

My problem: I can't find a way to get the `priority` property out of the `DBUs` interface.

According to the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/Developer/Clients/DBus/), neither the `Source` nor the `Device` Objects expose a property named `Priority`.
The only objects having a `Priority` field are `DevicePort` and `CardProfile`. I got the value for those properties but their value doesn't match with the output of `pacmd`.

Do you know if and where I can get the priority value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing getting the priority of sources is simply not possible.

There is an open merge request (by me) to add the support: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/531

In any case the subject is more complex than this.
In order to get the currently system-wide active microphone it's possible to use the `FallbackSource` property, but the user might have customized the microphone to be used by a specific app so a one size fits all solution doesn't exist.